Org Identifier given is not valid
When i initiate Catalyst project by running catalyst init command, i couldn't able to initiate, it throws an error.

HTTP Error: 403, Org identifier given is not valid
Error: The Catalyst portal initialized in the current project directory is not accessible with the currently logged in

Kindly give me solution to resolve this issue. I need to initiate a new project.

The error "Org identifier given is not valid" might occur if you have already initialized Catalyst project in the same directory, pointing to a different org ID.
To resolve this issue, delete the Catalyst configuration files such as .catalystrc and catalyst.json. Then, try initiating a project by running "catalyst init --force" command.
